# How to create a snippet in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 8.1. Snippets do not trigger

Tags: sublime-text-3, snippets

I cannot create a working snippet in ST3 on Windows 8.1. `tabTrigger` just doesn't print anything.

For instance, I want to create a snippet `@mixin` for `.scss` files. Here is how I create it.

```
Tools > New Snippet...
```

A new untitled file is opened that contains snippet's sample. I change it to my snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
@mixin ${1:mixin-name}(${2:var}) {
    ${3:...code...}
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>mix</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.scss</scope>
</snippet>
```

Then I type `Ctrl+S` and it opens a dialog window for saving the snippet. In my case it is in:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
```

I save it as `mixin-scss.sublime-snippet`. Then I go to `.scss` file type `mix` and tap `Tab` but nothing happens. Even if I reload ST3 it doesn't work. How to create a snippet on Windows 8.1? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your scope to source.scss instead of text.scss

Comment: Can you explain why your answer might work?  Provide a reference to support it?